# 20 000 000 hits; simple PHP/MySQL server using NGINX

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, http, traffic

I am hosting a big campaign that is going to launch tomorrow. The expected avg. number of visits on the first day is +200 000 users. Assuming everyone is going to visit 5 pages on avg., this makes 1 000 000 views x 20 static files, 20 000 000 requested.

The server I am using is:

```
Processor: Intel Core i5-2400 4x3.1+ GHz 6 MB L2 - QPI 5 GT/sec
Virtualisation: VT Instructions
Turbo Boost Technology: @ 3.40GHz
Architecture: 64 bits
RAM: 16 GB DDR3
Hard disk: Intel SSD 320 (2x 120 GB)
RAID: SOFT 0/1
NIC: FastEthernet
SwitchPort: 100 Mbps
```

The script itself doesn't involve many MySQL requests or complex PHP operations. Using HTTP server.

Should I upgrade my server or should this be enough to handle the traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Have you benchmarked your campaign page with `ab`, `siege`, `jmeter` or similar benchmarking software? Shoot the site with the benchmarking software of your choice, see how fast it is / how badly it kills your server.

The numbers themselves are not that high, so unless your campaign site is a resource hog, there shouldn't be problems.

Comment: Is there any online service instead? I know blitz.io, but they are using same IP to make all requests, which doesn't make it an accurate test. I've seen http://loadimpact.com/pricing but their pricing is ridiculous.

Comment: Why not ? The source IP is largely irrelevant. The requests are all that matter.

Comment: What's wrong with a good old smoke test `ab` etc. can provide to you? They WILL tell you if your site going down or going to survive your big day.

Answer (score 1):

A FastEthernet interface will have problems handling large numbers of connections.

If these requests are spread evenly over a 24-hour period, you are predicting on the order of 230 requests per second; this is not a huge amount, but it depends **entirely** on how long these requests take to process, and the size of the response.

- What is the mix of dynamic/static content for these requests ?
- Is the database accessed sanely, i.e. using persistent proxied connections?
- Is the database schema designed by a DBA, or an amateur ?

Do some local benchmarks using a web stress utility to figure out the answers to the above, and you will be able to better estimate the load this system can handle.